# AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android

i'm doing an android scheduled application , i use AlarmManager , but my alarm is not working , here are my code :

MyActivity :

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 44);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyBroadCastRcv.class), 0);
    getApplicationContext();
    AlarmManager alarmMngr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMngr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

MyBroadCastRcv class:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, TimerService.class);
    context.startService(serviceLauncher);

}
```

my Service :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onCreate();
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/sherif/001.mp3"));

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    System.out.println("In onStart Service");
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    player.start();
}
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: So do you get any error message or something?

Comment: no ,but the sound file is not played at the time i defined in the alarm

Comment: Are you sure "file:///mnt/sdcard/sherif/001.mp3" is correct?

Comment: ya when i run the service without the alarming function it works fine ..

Comment: Did you test this on a real device or the emulator? Because i don't believe it'll work on the emulator.

Comment: i'm doing all my testings on emulator.., for the sound file it;s working fine and i can hear the sound , but when using the alarm nothing happened ..!!

Comment: Well, you definitely **DO NOT** want to call `super.onCreate()` in `onStartCommand()`. Remove that and see what happens

Comment: after removing the OnCreate() in the onStartCommand(), the sound file now starts instantly as there is no alarm!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you definitely DO NOT want to call `super.onCreate()` in `onStartCommand()`. Remove that.

Also, your `onStart()` will never be called. This method is deprecated. You need to put all the code in `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: is there something i'm missing in the code ? ,because it's driving me crazy , all examples i saw are doing as i did !!

Comment: `onStart()` is deprecated. In the default implementation of `onStartCommand()`, it calls `onStart() for backwards compatibility with old code. Howver, you've overriden `onStartCommand()`. Oh, wait. I see. You are actually calling `super.onStartCommand()` which will then call your `onStart()`. This is still bad code. Move the call to `player.onStart()` into `onStartCommand()` and remove the `onStart()` method. That is cleaner and more understandable.

Comment: The reason that the sound file starts instantly is the way you've scheeduled the alarm. Obviously the alarm is going off immediately. Are you testing this before or after 1PM?

Comment: i did all your recommendations , my time now is 3.25 pm i tested it on 3.26 pm , as happened before it started instantly !!

Comment: Check that you are setting the Calendar correctly. Add logging like this after you've set the Calendar: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss a"); Log.v("app", "Time is " + format.format(calendar.getTime()));`

Comment: i figured a very weird thing that the emulator is 1 day ahead , for instance my laptop date is 11 November 2013 , the emulator date is 12 November 2013 !! so weird as far as i know it suppose to be as the host machine !! anyway i'll adjust it an see it my code will work probably or not